# How to boot Windows again after dual-booting Linux?

Tags: linux, dual-boot

Two months ago I successfully dual-booted PopOS using a USB on a Lenovo laptop which had Windows 11 pre-installed. I want to go back to using Windows. So far I have tried interrupting startup and looking through the settings, which show a ThinkPad display. Unfortunately, I cannot take a screenshot of it but I will describe what I see. I press F1 to enter the BIOS settings. Then I click on "Startup -> Boot", and what I see currently is the boot order. The top-most boot option is for the Linux OS, and right below it I see "Windows Boot Manager". I swapped the order to place the latter above the Linux OS, but this did not help me load Windows again on my laptop. What can I do? I am relatively new to using Linux so please bear with me.

Comment: if you still have acces to linux just update grub config file in most of cases it will add an entry to windows by running "sudo update-grub" , or if your lap supports efi you can press c letter when linux grub appears and write "chainloader (hd0,gpt1)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi" <hit enter> , and write "boot" <hit enter>

Comment: You booted PopOS from USB, but how did you install it to the laptop? You can go back to the original Windows only if you kept it.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani How do I check that I kept it? I don't think I did

Comment: @Yunus Could you explain what the grub file is? How do I find it? From the YouTube videos I have seen, it seems that a Boot Options page should open, from which I can easily switch back to Windows

Comment: The report that Boot-Repair creates will show your configuration. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Note that UEFI keeps entries even for deleted installs. So if you deleted Windows, you may still have a Windows UEFI boot entry and even Windows UEFI boot files in the ESP - efi system partition.